# How to use ngrok with fastapi on windows 10?

Tags: python, api, fastapi, ngrok

I'm trying to use ngrok to test a fastapi application. I'm working on a windows 10 machine. When I send the post request, I get a 405 Not Allowed error. In postman, the call works as expected if I use 127.0.0.1 but not if I use localhost. Therefore, I think this might be the issue but I don't know how to fix it. Has anyone experienced this issue before and know how to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: what do you have in `fastapi` ? Maybe it configured only for `127.0.0.1` (even if normally `localhost` means the same)

Comment: That was the confusing part for me. I thought the two were interchangeable so I don't know why I'm having this issue.

Comment: There is no traceback since the only error is coming from ngrok. It just says 405 not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that the hosts file isn't mapping 127.0.0.1 to localhost. Go to this folder:

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Open notepad as an admin and edit the "hosts" file. You need to make sure you have this line and it is uncommented.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Then restart your machine.